# Is it safe to open darknet websites on chrome?

Tags: anonymity, chrome

Yes, we can open darknet sites on latest chrome without appending any strings like *.to*. [image: https://check.torproject.org opened in chrome which says your browser is configured to use Tor.]

But my concern is risk of losing annonimity. Is their any such issues in accessing darknet via Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is very likely that you are track-able and depending on your settings and usage you may sooner or later reveal you identity.

there are reasons why [**Tor Browser**](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) is based on Firefox and not on Chromium... (and Chrome is even by far more worse!)

---

if you want anonymity and you are not sure what you are doing, please do the things and use the things as they are intended to work.
Additionally read the instructions (like at least [*Want Tor to really work?*](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning)) AND follow them!